# Contact Form Fields Are Displaying On The Site, But Data Not Being Pulled Through To Email

Tags: php, wordpress, forms

So I needed 2 new fields for this contact form, so I went into the contact.php in the shortcodes folder of the wordpress theme, and edited it to display on the website. It looks good on the site, but when I fill out the form and submit it, only the default fields get sent to my email address.

Here is the website, and below is the code: http://sellhouseforcashorlando.com/contact/

```
 // Contact Form
    add_shortcode('contact_form', 'theme_shortcode_contact_form');
    function theme_shortcode_contact_form($atts, $content = null, $code) {
        extract(shortcode_atts(array(
            'mail_to' => '',
            'form_id' => false,
            'button_color' => 'black'
        ), $atts));

        $id = mt_rand(0, 1000);
        $template_directory = get_template_directory_uri();
        $ajax_url = admin_url('admin-ajax.php');

        $mail_to = str_replace('@','[at]',$mail_to);

        $name_text = __('Name', 'theme_front');
        $email_text = __('Email', 'theme_front');
            $phonenumber_text = __('Phone Number', 'theme_front');
            $address_text = __('Property Address', 'theme_front');
        $message_text = __('Message', 'theme_front');
        $submit_text = __('Submit', 'theme_front');

        $form_id = ( $form_id ) ? '<input type="hidden" name="form-id" value="' . $form_id . '" />' : '';

        return <<<RET
    [raw]
    <form method="post" action="$ajax_url" id="form-$id" class="contact-form ajax-form validate-form">
        <div class="form-input-item clearfix">
            <label for="contact-form-$id-contact-name">$name_text <span class="required-star">*</span></label>
            <input type="text" class="input-text" name="contact-name-h" id="contact-form-contact-name-h">
            <input type="text" tabindex="8" size="22" value="" class="input-text {required:true}" name="contact-name" id="contact-form-$id-contact-name">
            <div class="form-error-box"></div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-input-item clearfix">
            <label for="contact-form-$id-contact-email">$email_text <span class="required-star">*</span></label>
            <input type="text" tabindex="9" size="22" value="" class="input-text {required:true, email:true}" name="contact-email" id="contact-form-$id-contact-email">
            <div class="form-error-box"></div>
        </div>

            <div class="form-input-item clearfix">
            <label for="contact-form-$id-contact-phonenumber">$phonenumber_text <span class="required-star">*</span></label>
            <input type="text" tabindex="9" size="22" value="" class="input-text {required:true}" name="contact-phonenumber" id="contact-form-$id-contact-phonenumber">
            <div class="form-error-box"></div>
        </div>

            <div class="form-input-item clearfix">
            <label for="contact-form-$id-contact-address">$address_text <span class="required-star">*</span></label>
            <input type="text" tabindex="9" size="22" value="" class="input-text {required:true}" name="contact-address" id="contact-form-$id-contact-address">
            <div class="form-error-box"></div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-input-item clearfix">
            <label for="contact-form-$id-contact-content">$message_text <span class="required-star">*</span></label>
            <textarea tabindex="10" rows="3" cols="30" class="input-textarea {required:true}" id="contact-form-$id-contact-content" name="contact-content"></textarea>
            <div class="form-error-box"></div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-response"></div>

        <div class="form-input-item form-input-item-last clearfix">
            <button class="button medium $button_color" type="submit"><span>$submit_text</span></button>
        </div>
        $form_id
        <input type="hidden" name="mail_to" value="$mail_to">
        <input type="hidden" name="action" value="do_contact" />
    </form>
```

Comment: You probably have to connect your new fields in the function that sends the email as well.

Comment: Thanks, do you know where I could find that?

Comment: I ended up figuring it out. Thanks for the direction